# Problem installing tmap r package ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, tmap

I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘lwgeom’ ...
** package ‘lwgeom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11
configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘lwgeom’
```

Previously I have follow this: https://philmikejones.me/tutorials/2018-08-29-install-sf-ubuntu/

sf and rgdal are installed without problem

I have other three machines with the same OS and have not encounter this issue before.

R version:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the exact same issue and I found a solution:

```
  devtools::install_github("r-spatial/lwgeom")
```

For reasons I can't comprehend, it seems that CRAN version doesn't get along with Ubuntu, but installing it via devtools allowed me to install lwgeom first and then tmaptools with no trouble at all. I hope it helps!